# How to Fetcing data from json array in android

Tags: android

My Json

```
{ 
    "version": "1.0",
    "dept": [ 
        {          
            "deptname": "Faculty"
        },
        {
            "deptname": "abc"
        },
        {
            "deptname": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "deptname": "hfc"
        }
    ],
    "success": "true",
    "errorcode": "200",
    "message": "dept list"
}
```

When i call an api it returns above data .

I want to get the `deptname` from this in a `list` in android

Answer (score 1):

```
{ // json object
    "version": "1.0",
    "dept": [ // jsonarray dept
        {            // jsonobject 
            "deptname": "Faculty" // string
        },
        {
            "deptname": "abc"
        },
        {
            "deptname": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "deptname": "hfc"
        }
    ],
    "success": "true",
    "errorcode": "200",
    "message": "dept list"
}
```

To parse

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("myjsonstring");
JSONArray jr = jb.getJSONArray("dept");
for(int i=0; i<jr.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
String name = jb.getString("deptname");
items.add(items);  
}
```

Comment: sir i m new in android ,i d't know how to call php api's.which return above data.so would u ple give the full exmple for calling api and handling the data

Comment: @ajay you need to make a http request to the url. You need to do network related operation on the thread or asnctask. Read the docs too much code involved